# How to solve imageview UI in XML ?( image size changing with Listview data.)

Tags: android

I test many ways to solve image view UI problem.

1)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1">              

            <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
                    ></ListView>            

            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/adv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"                                                     
                    ></ImageView>


</LinearLayout>
```

2)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1">              

            <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
                    ></ListView>            

            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/adv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"                                                 
                    ></ImageView>


</LinearLayout>
```

3)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1">              

            <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
                    ></ListView>            

            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/adv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                        
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"                                                 
                    ></ImageView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so you doesn't want to change size of image?

Comment: And what is that image view UI problem. you are facing please mention it here.

Comment: Actually whats your problem ? please mentioned clearly.

Comment: Yes,I don't want to change size of image. Image'size is changing with data from database,binding in ListView. I wanna to set image on the bottom of screen always,not changing size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Just Simple:




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @roitawng It's all my pleasure.